# Modular Arithmetic: solving a quadratic equation with a variable in the modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am not an expert on modulus arithmetic and I am computer scientist looking to see if there is a better way to solve an equation in the form of

$$(x^2 + 43) \mod (44-2x)=0$$

I am currently doing a linear search, I have other equations I am trying to solve other equations that are similar, but the search is becoming inefficient for large values. Any help would be appreciated.

The solutions to this equations are

$$x = -9,5,21,23$$

Comment: Have you found any $x$ satisfying this so far?

Comment: As a start, note that if $x$ is even, then $x^2+43$ is always odd and $44-2x$ is always even, and there is no multiple of an even number that results in an odd number,  i.e. leaving a residue of $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're looking to solve the equation over the integers.

First notice that when $x$ is even, then $x^2+43$ is odd, but the modulus is even. (The modulus is always even.) Therefore in order for $x$ to be a solution, $x$ must be odd. Let $x=2k+1$ then, for some integer $k$. Let's see if that simplifies things.

We now have 
$$4k^2+4k+44 \equiv 0 \pmod{2(2k-21)}.$$

Cancelling a $2$ from the equation and the modulus at the same time, we now have
$$2k^2+2k+22 \equiv 0 \pmod{2k-21},$$
which is much nicer.

The reason it's much nicer is that $2k-21$ has leading coefficient 2, which divides the leading coefficient of $2k^2+2k+22$. Thus, we can subtract the equation $(2k-21)k=2k^2-21k\equiv 0$ to get
$$23k + 22 \equiv 0 \pmod{2k-21},$$
and now we can subtract $11(2k-21)= 22k-231\equiv 0$
to get the equation
$$k+253\equiv 0 \pmod{2k-21}.$$

Now we rewrite this. We want to find for which $k$ there exist $q$ such that $k+253 = q(2k-21)$.

Rearranging, we have $(2q-1)k = 253+21q$

Thus, $k$ is a solution if and only if $k$ can be written as $\frac{21q+253}{2q-1}=10+\frac{q+263}{2q-1}$.

Thus we have reduced the question to figuring out when $\frac{q+263}{2q-1}$ is an  integer.

This is kind of a pain, so let's solve the much easier question of when it is an integer or a half integer, which we can solve by noting that in that case,
$$\frac{2(q+263)}{2q-1}=\frac{2q+526}{2q-1}=1+\frac{527}{2q-1}$$ will be an integer. Thus $2q-1$ will be a factor of $527$.

Note that $527$ is odd, so that $527/(2q-1)$ will always be odd, so that the resulting integer will always be even. This means that no value of $q$ gave a half integer solution, so every possible value of $q$ gives a value of $x$.
The factors of 527 are $\pm 1$,$\pm 17$,$\pm 31$, and $\pm 527$, 
corresponding to values for $q$ of $1,0,9,-8,16,-15$, $264$, and $-263$.

These give values of $k$ of $11,10,19,2,26,-5,274$, and $-253$.
Thus we get solutions for $x$ of $23,21,39,5,53,-9,549$, and $-505$.

Comment: Could explain where you get the form for the k solutions as $21q+2532/q−1=10+q+2632/q−1$

Comment: @RyanTopps, to get the first thing, I took the equation on the line above and divided by $2q-1$, then I simplified by doing polynomial long division of the numerator by the denominator. Try finding a common denominator on the right hand side to check that the lhs and rhs are equal.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. Unfortunately getting prime factors will be even harder than a search at large values, but your replacements showed me how to scan more effectively so thank you.

Comment: @Ryan Prime factorization is required to solve such problems, but we can do the rest more quickly - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ x\!-\!22\mid x^2\!+\!43-(x\!-\!22)(x\!+\!22)  = 527= 17\cdot 31\,$ so $\,x\, =\, 22\pm\{1,17,31,527\}$

Answer (score 0):

For $x=21$, $44-2x=2$ and the residue of any even number is $0\mod 2$.

$21^2+43$ is even.

Comment: Yes I am was more concerned with finding the x values of -9,5,21,23

Comment: The value $23$ results in a negative modulus $(-2)$ which is a highly unusual usage.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if

$$x^2 + 43 \equiv 0 \pmod{44 - 2x} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

then multiplying by $-2$ gives

$$-2x^2 - 86 \equiv 0 \pmod{44 - 2x} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Also, dividing $44 - 2x$ into $-2x^2 - 86$ gives

$$-2x^2 - 86 = \left(x + 22\right) \left(44 - 2x\right) - 1054 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Thus, your original equation can be simplified to just look for cases where

$$-1054 \equiv 0 \pmod{44 - 2x} \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

As such, you only need to check cases where $44 - 2x$ is a factor of $1054 = 2 * 31 * 17$, in particular, $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 31, \pm 17, \pm 62, \pm 34, \pm 527, \pm 1054$.  For each value $n$ among these factors, you can then solve for $x$ by using $x = 22 - \frac{n}{2}$.  As such, for integral values of $x$, the factor must be even, giving the results of $x = 21, 23, -9, 53, 5, 39, -505, 549$.

Also, if you wish to avoid using negative modulus values, then you need to have $44 - 2x \gt 0$, so $x \lt 22$, giving the results of just $x = -505, -9, 5, 21$.

Comment: What you showed me with this that all answers comes in pairs where their sum is 44, which is a quite interesting approach.

Comment: @RyanTopps In general, I am showing here that if you have a quadratic equation of a square term and a constant on the left, and a linear equation as the modulus, you can simplify it to just a constant, as I have shown here.  I could have done it for a more general case, but I thought it would be simpler, and possibly more useful, to show the specific case you asked for.  I hope you can see how this technique works so you can apply it in any other similar situations.

Comment: I appreciate it, its just to find prime factors is not an easy solution in programming. I am merely looking a way for me to "cheat" so to say so I do not have to scan from 0 to 44. Basically calculating the modulus is one of the fastest operations.

Comment: @RyanTopps Note that your solution doesn't include the answer of $-505$.  If you plug it into your original equation, the the modulus becomes $1054$, with the left side becomes $255068 = 242 \times 1054$.